# What unicode characters are between hex 7E and A0?

Tags: unicode

What is the unicode between 0x7E and 0xA0?

Looking on charmap  it shows 7E then A0   I know 7F is a control character. But that still leaves the rest up to just before A0, so the characters of 7F-9F are still a mystery.

[image]

And in case it was that that font wasn't supporting unicode well, I tried Arial too.

And looking on wikipedia on this page gives me no clue

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode
[image]

And looking  http://unicode-table.com/en/#basic-latin  also no clue

I know ASCII is 7 bit, so that takes us from 0-7F  and I know 7F in ASCII is a control character. And apparently still is in unicode  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7f/index.htm

But what are the characters  between 7F and 9F i.e. 7F to just before A0?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29), you have the list.

> The C1 Controls subheading contains 32 supplementary control codes inherited from ISO/IEC 8859-1 and many other 8-bit character standards.

They are non printable characters like `End of Selected Area`, `Reverse Line Feed`, `Break Permitted Here`

It also shows on [unicode-table.com](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/latin-1-supplement/)  which is in your question - though on that page they show as blank initially, but you can hover the mouse cursor over a character (or click on it) and it shows the description.

Comment: Sorry, wikiwand is a firefox plugin for wikipedia, I have updated the link

Comment: turns out wikiwand has the same articles as wikipedia it describes itself as having a sleaker interface.. i see the article also on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29  so you were right